# Me aparece un error al renderizar la vista en el servidor creado con node js, Error: Cannot find module 'js'

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, server

soy nuevo en Nodejs y estoy teniendo problemas para renderizar la vista en el navegador, he creado un servidor con nodejs que corre en el puerto 3000, pero por alguna razón que desconozco me aparece el siguiente error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'js'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\hugo.bustamante\Desktop\Codeando\Web con Nodej y express js\web-docker\node_modules\express\lib\view.js
- C:\Users\hugo.bustamante\Desktop\Codeando\Web con Nodej y express js\web-docker\node_modules\express\lib\application.js
- C:\Users\hugo.bustamante\Desktop\Codeando\Web con Nodej y express js\web-docker\node_modules\express\lib\express.js
- C:\Users\hugo.bustamante\Desktop\Codeando\Web con Nodej y express js\web-docker\node_modules\express\index.js
- C:\Users\hugo.bustamante\Desktop\Codeando\Web con Nodej y express js\web-docker\src\index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at new View (C:\Users\hugo.bustamante\Desktop\Codeando\Web con Nodej y express js\web-docker\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:81:14)
    at Function.render (C:\Users\hugo.bustamante\Desktop\Codeando\Web con Nodej y express js\web-docker\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:587:12)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\hugo.bustamante\Desktop\Codeando\Web con Nodej y express js\web-docker\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1039:7)
    at C:\Users\hugo.bustamante\Desktop\Codeando\Web con Nodej y express js\web-docker\src\index.js:8:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\hugo.bustamante\Desktop\Codeando\Web con Nodej y express js\web-docker\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\hugo.bustamante\Desktop\Codeando\Web con Nodej y express js\web-docker\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
```

Este es el codigo que tengo en el servidor:

```
const express = require('express');
const app= express(); //iniciamos express

const PORT= 3000;
app.use(express.static('src/public')); //empezamos el servicio de los archivos staticos

app.get( '/', (req, res) => {//renderizamos nuestra vista, plantilla
    res.render("index.js");
});

//Corremos el servidor
app.listen( PORT, () => console.log(`corriendo el servidor en el puerto ${PORT}`));
```

Envio una captura para que vean como tengo estructurado el proyecto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco mucho cualquier ayuda

Comment: Ya ensayaste borrar la carpeta `node_modules` y hacer `npm install` de nuevo?

Comment: Podrías incluir el código del index?

Comment: Sip, ya lo hice pero no me funciona tampoco. En el index.js está el mismo código del servidor que ya subí en el post y pues en el index.html solo está el código normal que imprime solo un "Hola mundo" en una etiqueta <h2>

Comment: Pero es que estas mandando a renderizar index.js deberias mandar es index.html

Comment: voy a probarlo porque no creo que sea eso ya que saque todos los archivos y los puse en la raiz del directorio y allí me funciona bien, se renderiza el archivo index.js, ya que este se manda a llamar como un script dentro del html